# QGIS Server install on Windows using XAMPP

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, configuration

I am trying to understand the basics of QGIS Server/Desktop.  I am trying to get WMS and WFS to work on a Windows 2016 Server.  I am using https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows (QGIS 3.16) as the install guide.

My first question is are there any recommendations or requirements regarding both server and desktop being on the same server such as an LTR version of one and non-LTR for the other?

Also, I have seen other guides say that the Full desktop version is needed for all the necessary features to be installed but I don't know if that is accurate for the current XAMPP path.

Comment: qgis server and desktop version must be the same and installed on the same server.  You can use any web server you don't need to use XAMPP.  The specification of your server will depend on web traffic you expect

Comment: When I put this in the web browser    http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&MAP=c:/qgis-xampp2/apps/qgis/doc/images/projects/world/world2.qgs&LAYERS=continents&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400   I get a black web page with a white rectangle in the middle.  Based on previous error messages it appears it finds the projects, and identifies the layers but no map or layer is returned.  Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&MAP=c:/qgis-xampp2/apps/qgis/doc/images/projects/world/world2.qgs&LAYERS=continents&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400` is not a complete GetMap request, you're missing mandatory parameters BBOX, STYLES, FORMAT

Comment: Thank you.  All the documentation should those parameters were not required.